# Power bi e NPS - Como mostrar Medida como evolução no gráfico de barras

Tags: powerbi

Eu tenho uma base de dados, de uma pesquisa NPS Reduzida para facilitar a explicação do meu problema, segue abaixo

[Base de Dados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdpMw.png)

Somar a quantidade de Promotores - Notas 9 e 10 e Diminuir pela quantidade de Detratores, para identificar as Notas NPS de cada serviço.

Eu criei uma coluna temporaria (Classificação), onde escreve Promotores, se for 09 ou 10. Qt. P Serviço de Email = CALCULATE([Qt. NU Serviço de Email], 'Pesquisas'[Classificação] = "Promotores")

Depois identifico os Detratores Qt. D Serviço de Email = CALCULATE([Qt. NU Serviço de Email], 'Pesquisas'[Classificação] = "Detratores")

Pego a porcentagem de Cada um com relação a quantidade total de registros % P Recomendaria = DIVIDE([Qt. P Recomendaria], [Qt. NPS Recomendaria])

E faço a conta para chegar no NPS Resultado NPS Recomendaria = ('Medidas'[% P Recomendaria] - 'Medidas'[% D Recomendaria])

Faço isso para cada serviço.

PROBLEMA IDENTIFICADO

Dessa forma, eu tenho os Serviços com resultado Separado no Medida.

O QUE EU PRECISO

Mostrar em um gráfico de Barras esse Resultado. Exemplo

[RESULTADO DESEJADO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNwUc.png)